# Need to generate a random number that includes at least one number in iOS

Tags: ios, random

I have a random number generator method in iOS that I am currently using.  While it is working fine, I would like to modify it such that in its output, it ALWAYS includes at least one number.  How would I do this?  Here is the random number method that I am using:

```
- (NSString *)generateRandString {

    NSString *alphabet  = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXZY0123456789";
    NSMutableString *s = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:5];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0U; i < 5; i++) {

        u_int32_t r = arc4random() % [alphabet length];
        unichar c = [alphabet characterAtIndex:r];
        [s appendFormat:@"%C", c];

    }

    return s;
}
```

Thanks in advance to all who reply.

Comment: Before returning `s`, make sure it contains a number. If not, generate a new string.

Comment: You realise that this process detracts from its randomness?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my edited and checked solution:

```
- (NSString *)generateRandString {

         NSString *alphabet  = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXZY0123456789";
         NSMutableString *s;
         NSCharacterSet *set = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];

         do
        {
            s = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:5];
           for (NSUInteger i = 0U; i < 5; i++)
           {

              u_int32_t r = arc4random() % [alphabet length];
              unichar c = [alphabet characterAtIndex:r];
              [s appendFormat:@"%C", c];
            }
       }
       while ([s rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set].location == NSNotFound);  

      return s;
 }
```

I've also implemented the solution suggested by Dan Dyer (and it's obviously better than mine). My implementation is probably not perfect ( i use the same functionality few times instead of creating a separate function for it, but i believe it's not difficult to implement for you) but it works exactly as Dan has proposed.

```
  NSString *alphabet  = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXZY0123456789";
NSMutableString *s  = [NSMutableString string];
NSCharacterSet *set = [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];
NSString *digits    = @"0123456789";

for (NSUInteger i = 0U; i < 4; i++)
{
    u_int32_t r = arc4random() % [alphabet length];
    unichar c = [alphabet characterAtIndex:r];
    [s appendFormat:@"%C", c];
}

if ([s rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set].location == NSNotFound)
{
    u_int32_t r = arc4random() % [digits length];
    unichar c = [digits characterAtIndex:r];
    [s appendFormat:@"%C", c];
}
else
{
    u_int32_t r = arc4random() % [alphabet length];
    unichar c = [alphabet characterAtIndex:r];
    [s insertString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", c] atIndex:arc4random() % s.length];
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your prompt reply.  I tried your solution, but I am getting the following error:  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attempt to mutate immutable object with appendFormat:'  Do you see what the problem is?  Thanks once again for your help.

Comment: Thanks once again.  It is running, but I am unable to get a number in the output.

Comment: do you mean it doesn't contain a number?

Comment: Correct.  My output is just letters.

Comment: i changed one more line. try again.

Comment: Dan Dyer suggested solution better than mine. i think it must be accepted

Comment: I've corrected my answer and checked it in Xcode. Now it works as you need

Answer (score 2):

Rather than generating the whole string and then rejecting it if it doesn't contain any digits, which could take many iterations before it generates a valid string (there is a 41.5% chance that any 5-character string you generate won't contain a digit), a more efficient approach would be to keep track while generating the string.

If you want to generate a 5-character string, first generate 4 characters.  If at least one of these is a digit you can generate the fifth character normally.  If it's not, select only from the set of digits for the fifth character.  If you want to avoid biasing the position of the numeric digits, you can insert this fifth character at a random position rather than tacking it on the end.